# Scala: Wrapping params/arguments

Tags: scala

It'll probably be better if I give an example of what I'm trying to do. Say I have something like this:

```
def foo(a: String, b: String, c: String) = ...

object Bar {
  val a = "a"
  val b = "b"
  val c = "c"

  def fooArgs = a, b, c // not possible but it's shows what I'm trying to do
}
```

Doing this would be too much *(Keep in mind that I can not change how `foo` is defined)

```
foo(Bar.a, Bar.b, Bar.c)
```

I was wondering if it's possible to do something like this:

```
foo(Bar.fooArgs)
```

How can I do this using scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    def foo(a: String, b: String, c: String) = 0

    object Bar {
      val fooArgs = ("a", "b", "c")
    }

    foo.tupled(Bar.fooArgs)
```

Comment: Getting `ambiguous reference to overloaded definition` even though `foo(Bar.a, Bar.b, Bar.c)` works fine

Comment: @Jon if foo is overloaded, you can select which you want with this grotesquery: `(X.foo _: ((String,String,String)=>String)).tupled((a,b,c))`